# Import issue with __init__.py file Python: loading one subpackage automatically imports all the other subpackages

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I have a python package with this structure:

```
package/
       __init__.py
       subA/
           __init__.py
           A.py
       subB/
           __init__.py
           B.py
```

In `package/__init__.py` I have added two statements:

```
import subA
import subB
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to import the whole package using `import package` and be able to use `package.aubA` and `package.subB`.

It works, however I can't load only `package.subA`. If I use `import package.subA` then also `package.subB` is imported. If I use `import package.subA as sA` then only sA is available.

Is this the normal behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?
How can I chose to import all the statements using `import package` or only individual subpackages without loading all the others?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. Since you have

```
import subA
import subB
```

If you add a few print statements in your `__init__.py` files you will understand it better. When you do an import like `import package.subA`, it is `'package'` that gets imported.

`This is package's __init__ file`

`This is subA's __init__ file`

`This is subB's __init__ file`

Doing a print dir() would also add more clarity.

When you do `import package.subA`

`['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'package']`

When you do `import package.subA as sA`

`['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'sA']`

Comment: Thanks! From what I could understand adding the print statements, when I `import package.subA` package/__init__.py is executed first, which load all the subpackages. But still I don't see how I can fix it so that I can load only one subpackage when needed without loading the others and being able to import all of them when I need them all.

Comment: You mean to say that you want `from package import subA` functionality to be available as `package.subA`. Hmmm. Let me try something.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on **why** you would need to do something? Probably based on the reasons, I could think of an alternate way of doing things!

Comment: No I don't want what you say. I want to be able to import each individual subpackage without importing all the others; i.e. when I import package.subA I don't want package.subB to be imported.

However there may be cases when I want to import both package.subA and package.subB and would like to do that simply by issuing an 'import package' statement.

Comment: I honestly feel that you are complicating things. Using the `as` functionality of python will simplify things for you. In any other case, you should have think twice before writing complicated code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) but I am not complicating things I think.
It is quite a common behaviour, for example you can import numpy.polynomial without importing all the numpy package...

Comment: I tried the numpy example you cited. The entire numpy package does get imported. 
>>> import numpy.polynomial
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'numpy']
>>>

Comment: ..you are right.. I just think it is a waste to load the whole package when you only need a submodule...